# How to handle variable shape bias in TensorFlow?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I was just modifying some an LSTM network I had written to print out the test error. The issues, I realized, is that the model I had defined depends on the batch size.

Specifically, the input is a tensor of shape `[batch_size, time_steps, features]`. The input enters the LSTM cell and the output, which I turn into a list of `time_steps` 2D tensors, with each 2D tensor having shape `[batch_size, hidden_units]`. Each 2D tensor is then multiplied by a weight vector of shape `[hidden_units]` to yield a vector of shape `[batch_size]` which has added to it a bias vector of shape `[batch_size]`.

In words, I give the model `N` sequences, and I expect it to output a scalar for each time step for each sequence. That is, the output is a list of `N` vectors, one for each time step.

For training, I give the model batches of size 13. For the test data, I feed the entire data set, which consists of over 400 examples. Thus, an error is raised, since the bias has fixed shape `batch_size`.

I haven't found a way to make it's shape variable without raising an error.

I can add complete code if requested. **Added code anyways.**

Thanks.

```
def basic_lstm(inputs, number_steps, number_features, number_hidden_units, batch_size):

weights = {
'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([number_hidden_units, 1]))
}

biases = {
'out': tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[batch_size, 1]))
}

lstm_cell = rnn.BasicLSTMCell(number_hidden_units)
init_state = lstm_cell.zero_state(batch_size, dtype=tf.float32)

hidden_layer_outputs, states = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(lstm_cell, inputs,
   initial_state=init_state, dtype=tf.float32)

results = tf.squeeze(tf.stack([tf.matmul(output, weights['out']) 
    + biases['out'] for output 
    in tf.unstack(tf.transpose(hidden_layer_outputs, (1, 0, 2)))], axis=1))

return results
```

Answer (score -2):

You want the biases to be a shape of (batch_size, )

For example (using zeros instead of tf.constant but similar problem), I was able to specify the shape as a single integer:

```
biases = tf.Variable(tf.zeros(10,dtype=tf.float32))
print(biases.shape)
```

prints:

```
(10,)
```